# How to add items in an array inside mongodb (mongoose)?

Tags: node.js, database, mongodb, mongoose, nosql

I have a "cart" model and an "order" model, in my "order" model, I have a "list" which is an array that in theory receives a cart item by reference. The issue is that I would like to receive more than one cart per id and store them all in an array, not just receive one. How could I do this?

order model

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const OrderSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
    {
        list: [{
            type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
            ref: 'Cart',
        }],
        totalAmount: {
            type: Number,
            required: true,
        },
        payment: {
            type: String,
            required: true,
        },
        address: {
            type: String,
            required: true,
        },
        addressNote: {
            type: String,
            required: false,
        },
        createdAt: {
            type: Date,
            default: Date.now,
        }
    },
    { timestamps: true }
  );
  
module.exports = mongoose.model("Order", OrderSchema);
```

cart model

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const CartSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
    {
        name: {
            type: String,
            required: true,
        },
        note: [{
            type: String,
            required: false,
        }],
        quantity: {
            type: Number,
            required: true,
            default: 1,
        },
        price: {
            type: Number,
            required: false,
        },
        createdAt: {
            type: Date,
            default: Date.now,
        }
    },
    { timestamps: true }
  );
  
module.exports = mongoose.model("Cart", CartSchema);
```

order controller / store

```
const Order = require('../../models/Order');

class CreateOrder {
    async create(req, res) {
        const { list, totalAmount, payment, address } = req.body;

        try {
            const order = await Order.create({
                list,
                totalAmount,
                payment,
                address,
            });

            return res.status(200).json(order);
        } catch (err) {
            return res.status(500).json(err);
        }
    }
} 

module.exports = new CreateOrder();
```

Comment: Your question is not clear. Can you pl elaborate ?

Comment: You need to pass an array of `Order`s' `_id`s as `list` in the `body`.

Comment: I would like to send more than a single cart in "list" in the order model, I would like them all to be stored in this array

Comment: @lpizzinidev Yes, but how can I send more than one id and store more than one cart item?

Comment: @Routfin It depends on your front-end logic. Can you post the code where you send the request to the server?